# Php/Mysql Query to list by letter group

Tags: php, mysql

How do I do a query and code it on php?

My query from sql are names but I want this to be listed on php where it groups by names that starts with A, B, C and so on like below.

My code runs like this

```
$sqlquery = <squery string>  
$d=sql(sqlquery)  
while(fetch(d))  
{  
echo data   
}
```

I want it to be echo list as below

**A**
Aron
Accel
Aman
**B**
Balter
Balbon
Basty
**C**
.
.
.
**Z**

How do I run a check every time it starts with every new letter it will echo first starting letter first to group as the query runs through? I want to do it in one query so I don't have to run a query to match each starting letter to group them.

Comment: `$start = ''; while(fetch($d)){.. if($start != $row['field'][0]){ $start = $row['field'][0]; showsomeletterhtml($start);}..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing too complex with it, just use something like that:

```
$sqlquery = <squery string>  
$d=sql(sqlquery) 
$firstletter = ''; 
while(fetch(d))  
{
 if (substr(d, 0, 1) !== $firstletter) {
  if (!empty($firstletter)) {echo '</div><hr />';}
  $firstletter = substr(d, 0, 1);
  echo '<div>'.$firstletter;
 }
 echo d;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if thats right. From what I see it on the checking ti starts with checking the first letter of the data and if not equal to the $firstletter which is empty it will then get the firstletter of the empty variable and echo nothing at all.  I am trying to do a check within the while statement that whenever there's a first new letter it will first echo the that letter(A-Z) so that the data  are group by letters

Comment: That's it. I now get it. It works. Unbelievable. It worked really as I wanted. Thank you so much. I know the substr but I could not get the logic on how to do the checking. My codes always display all the initial letter on every data. You really save me on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a follow up. I'm bit confused. How do I add an hr line every after before it starts a letter group of A,B ,C...? But I do not want the line to appear on top of A. Am trying to group them inside a div for each group letter.

Comment: There you are, the latest update should be your solution. Please do not forget to mark my reply as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is run this query

**Note some people will see this as wrong because you use SQL to format HTML code but you get very clean client side code**

```
select 
   UPPER(LEFT(name.name, 1)) "capital"
 , GROUP_CONCAT( name.name SEPARATOR '<br />') "name_formatted"
from
 name

group by 
 capital asc
```

see this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ec58/8
One bad thing is the "using filesort" so it's better to have an separated start capital column in your database

If you run that query and fetch it you get an array like this..

```
$names = array(
    'A' => 'Aron<br />Accel<br />Aman'
  , 'B' => 'Balter<br />Balbon<br />Basty'
);
```

What wil be very easy to loop (note example loop)

```
foreach ($names as $capital => $name_formatted) {
  echo '<b>' . $capital . '</b>' . '<br />';
  echo $name_formatted . '<br />';
}
```

What will output

```
A
Aron
Accel
Aman
B
Balter
Balbon
Basty
```

Comment: Clever approach but surely does work too. I didn't realized nor knew that it's possible to have an html code over a sql statement. Thanks a lot on this. Surely helpful too.

Comment: You don't even need to have an FROM and table name in your statement atleast with MySQL SELECT "<b>HTML</b>" as "html"; but this is clearly abuse..